# delay in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

Tags: ios, notifications, swift2, push

For some reason in my iOS app there is a delay of a few minutes between
registerForRemoteNotifications and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

sometimes its as much as 5 minutes 
any ideas why that could be?

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
func requestPushNotification() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert, UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound, UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge]) { (success, error) in
            if success {
                //UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
                let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            } else {
                if error != nil {
                    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error!)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("willPresentNotification")
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    print("didReceiveNotificationResponse")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    if notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationType() {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
    print(error)
}
}
```

and

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
}
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: Have you checked with other networks ?

Comment: yes internet connection seems unrelated

Comment: May be related as it harldy takes a minute to register